# Can we assign heap size to each application on a JVM?

Tags: java, heap-memory

Suppose there 3 apps deployed on one jvm A,B and C. Can I assign 5 Gb to app A alone ?
In our case we are using WebLogic application server on Linux.

Comment: what kind of your application web application or desktop app? if a web app what server you are using? If your application run in a Server, mean a web application you can set this configuration in your Server

Comment: 1. what kind of applications? In servlet container, JEE? 2. Read about docker. Not so simple, but with strong resources control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why have one JVM per application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539132/why-have-one-jvm-per-application)

Comment: We are using WebLogic App Server

Comment: No. There is only one heap in a JVM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're stuck, unless you try some dark voodoo that gets into the JVM internals. I wouldn't suggest going down that path unless you *absolutely, positively* must.

In any event, here's what WebLogic provides in terms of heap space (warning: it's generally the same fundamental concepts as CLI launched apps)

https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/weblogic_server_performance_and_tuning

> Each WebLogic Server instance runs in its own dedicated Java Virtual
>   Machine (JVM) which is their runtime environment. Every Admin Server
>   in any domain executes within a JVM. The same also applies for Managed
>   Servers. WebLogic Server can be used for a wide variety of
>   applications and services which uses the same runtime environment and
>   resources. Oracle WebLogic ships with 2 different JVM, HotSpot and
>   JRocket but you can choose which JVM you want to use.
>
> JVM is designed to optimize itself however it also provides some
>   startup options to make small changes. There are default values for
>   its memory and garbage collection. In real world, you will not want to
>   stick with the default values provided by the JVM rather want to
>   customize these values based on your applications which can produce
>   large gains in performance by making small changes with the JVM
>   parameters. We can tell the garbage collector how to delete garbage
>   and we can also tell JVM how much space to allocate for each
>   generation (of java Objects) or for heap. Remember during the garbage
>   collection no other process is executed within the JVM or runtime,
>   which is called STOP THE WORLD which can affect the overall
>   throughput.
>
> Each JVM has its own memory segment called Heap Memory which is the
>   storage for java Objects. These objects can be grouped based on their
>   age like young generation (recently created objects) or old generation
>   (surviving objects that have lived to some extent), etc. A java object
>   is considered garbage when it can no longer be reached from anywhere
>   in the running program. Each generation has its own memory segment
>   within the heap. When this segment gets full, garbage collector
>   deletes all the objects that are marked as garbage to create space.
>   When the old generation space gets full, the JVM performs a major
>   collection to remove the unused objects and reclaim their space. A
>   major garbage collect takes a significant amount of time and can
>   affect system performance.

It then goes on to describe the specific parameters to toggle for heap space.