# what is it meant by stop the JVM with exit()?

Tags: java, jvm

They could be many JVMs per Operative system or it is only one JVM per Operative System ? I also read that with "Runtime.exit()", we stop the execution of a JVM?

I'm a bit confuse because I've always thought that JVM is a machine that never stop working, always awaken waiting to be called for example by the "java App.class".

Comment: related question : [Is there one jvm per java application ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947207/is-there-one-jvm-per-java-application)

Comment: Also, you would never say `java App.class`. It's always `java App`; the JRE adds the .class

Answer (score 0):

The JVM is an abstract concept, and there may be many running instances per Operating System. The implementation is usually through the Java Runtime Environment. And when `exit` is called, the runtime stops. The JVM can certainly stop. And (on most computers) it has to be explicitly started.

Answer (score 0):

> i'have always thougth that JVM is a machine that never stop working, always awaken waiting to be called for example by the "java App.class"

No, that is not how the JVM works. It's not a background process that is waiting to execute your Java programs. There is not always just one JVM running on one computer.

Whenever you start a Java program, a new JVM is started. When you have multiple Java programs running at the same time, you have multiple JVMs running. Each program is running in its own JVM.

`System.exit()` stops the JVM that is running the current Java application. It has no effect on other Java programs running on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a java app (directly or indirectly with the `java` shell command), then an instance of the JVM is created and started.

When the application finishes (either by reaching the end or through `System.exit()` then the JVM instance stops.

Of course, you can have multiple Java apps running simultaneously. Each will be in its own JVM instance.

Answer (score 0):

> They could be many JVMs per Operative system or it is only one JVM per Operative System ?

You can do either.  You can run a JVM for each command, or you can use an application server to run your java applications. (You cna have more than one application server)

> I also read that with "Runtime.exit()", we stop the execution of a JVM ?

This triggers the JVM to shutdown. The process does some work such as calling Shutdown Hooks after this is called.

> i' m a bit confuse because i'have always thougth that JVM is a machine that never stop working,

It can be used that way.  For example scala has a daemon compiler which is used to compile scala programs.

> always awaken waiting to be called for example by the "java App.class".

When you run any program, (java or not) this always starts a new program.  The *only* time this doesn't happen is for built in shell commands. e.g. `set`