# Confused about Java Memory

Tags: java

This is a very basic question but I could not find any proper answer to this and it always confuses me. So thought of posting here.

1. Does 2 Java Applications running on same machine share same JVM or every Java Application has its own JVM?
2. On a multi-core processor does my Java application memory is shared across processors?
3. Is it possible to update my applications cache from outside the application? - like running a cron job at regular interval to update few variables in my application. Is this possible?

Comment: Question 3 is very, *very* different. You should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: for question 1  and 2 you can refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947207/is-there-one-jvm-per-java-application) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436422/how-does-java-makes-use-of-multiple-cores) respectively.

Comment: You can do 3 but it's a very bad idea. Instead you should communicate with the application so it updates what ever values need to be changed.