# Why Only one SparkContext is allowed per JVM?

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, rdd

This question was asked in interview that how many sparkcontexts are allowed to be created per JVM and why?
I know only one sparkContext is allowed per jvm but cant understand why?
Would anyone please help me understand the reason behind "one sparkcontext per jvm"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple - it has not been designed to work with multiple contexts. [Quoting Reynold Xin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243?focusedCommentId=14041844&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14041844):

> I don't think we currently support multiple SparkContext objects in the same JVM process. There are numerous assumptions in the code base that uses a a shared cache or thread local variables or some global identifiers which prevent us from using multiple SparkContext's.

In a broader sense - single application (with `main`), single JVM - is standard approach in Java world ([Is there one JVM per Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5947207), [Why have one JVM per application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13539132)). Application servers choose different approach, but it is exception, not a rule.

From practical point of view - handling single data intensive application is painful enough (tuning GC, dealing with leaking resources, communication overhead). Mutliple Spark applications running in a single JVM would be impossible to tune and manage in a long run.

Finally there would not be much use of having multiple contexts, as each distributed data structure is tightly connected to its context.