# How java works in android through memory object heap allocation

Tags: java, android, memory-management, stack, heap-memory

I am new to **Android** but experienced in **Java**.
In **Java** when we do this:

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
```

It clearly does the following:

1. Inserts the memory pointer `myObj` upto the stack
2. Allocates a new space for object of type `MyClass` in the heap
3. Appoints this new space's reference to `myObj`

But I am a little bit confused about the following questions:

1. But in **Android**, does this work in the same way?
2. Does **Android** have full stack and heap memories?
3. Does **Android** have Java Virtual Machine (JVM) for my **Java** app (**Android** app) to work on?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: wonder what all this Oracle vs Google fuss is about?

Comment: (First Question Review) The question is well written. Personally I wondered a bit why you think Android/Dalvik would be any different. If you add that, then you might get more targeted answers.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588076/is-dalviks-memory-model-the-same-as-javas

Answer (score 3):

Android re-implemented the Java Virtual Machine with their own Dalvik Virtual Machine. Unlike the **JVM** which is stack-based, **Dalvik** is register based. You can see a comparison between the two here:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)#Performance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29#Performance)

Yes Dalvik VM has a heap just like the JVM - just not a stack. It is 100% compatible with any Java 1.6 source code (1.7 support is slowly coming, and preliminary support is available in Android Studio). So in your 3 steps:

1. Inserts the reference to myObj in a register
2. Allocates a new space for object of type MyClass in the heap
3. Appoints this new space's reference to myObj

Comment: Here's another reference if you're still looking for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446540/what-is-the-difference-between-dvm-and-jvm