# DVM ensure that multiple instances run efficiently on a single device ! what does that mean?

Tags: java, android, jvm, dalvik

Hello guys I'm having a problem in understanding this term, I was looking into the deference between JVM and DVM and this is one of the major differences but I don't really understand it.
I would really appreciate it if anyone could help and explain it in details for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this:

Dalvik is a process virtual machine (VM) in Google's Android operating system that executes applications written for Android. This makes Dalvik an integral part of the Android software stack (in Android versions 4.4 "KitKat" and earlier) that is typically used on mobile devices such as mobile phones and tablet computers, as well as more recently on devices such as smart TVs and wearables.

Programs are commonly written in Java and compiled to bytecode for the Java virtual machine, which is then translated to Dalvik bytecode and stored in .dex (Dalvik EXecutable) and .odex (Optimized Dalvik EXecutable) files; related terms odex and de-odex are associated with respective bytecode conversions. The compact Dalvik Executable format is designed for systems that are constrained in terms of memory and processor speed.

Dalvik is open-source software. It was originally written by Dan Bornstein, who named it after the fishing village of Dalvík in Eyjafjörður, Iceland.

[Refrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software))

Comment: You can say it is a advance version of JVM,  which is used by Netbeans

Comment: i'm not looking for the Dalvik explanation i know what it is, my problem is that i don't understand the term "run multiple instances" what does that mean ? multiple instances !! thanks

Comment: i think there is mistake. It should be " Dalvik has been written so that a device can run multiple VMs efficiently."  
also provide link where you have read this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446540/what-is-the-difference-between-dvm-and-jvm, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577733/how-an-android-application-is-executed-on-dalvik-virtual-machine,

Comment: As far as I understood , what they mean by Multiple instances , they are talking about virtual machine .  And as far as they are talking about same device , I think they are talking about same machine. Like If I can play multiple instance of virtual machine on my this machine(Device)